# How to split text file elements using a windows batch file?

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file

I have a text file `RECORDS` containing a list of addresses to series of record files from `physionet` website:

```
Person_01/rec_1
Person_01/rec_2
.
.
.
Person_90/rec_1
Person_90/rec_2
```

I need to execute a command as below to each line of text file as below:

```
wfdb2mat -r rec_1 -f 0 -t 20 > rec_1m.info
```

Here, `wfdb2mat` is the command known to windows to convert `.dat` data structure in windows to `.mat` structure known to `MATLAB`. Output report of this command execution is stored as `.info` in the same directory as `RECORDS` line.

I have written a batch file (convert.bat) as:

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in (RECORDS) do (wfdb2mat -r %%~a -f 0 -t 20 > %%~am.info)
```

to convert all files listed in `RECORDS`.
But unfortunately, there are two other files naming `.mat` and `.hea` which are store in the same directory as `convert.batch` and named `rec_Xm.mat` and `rec_Xm.hea`, where X is the record number listed in `RECORDS`.

Thus, I need to add an extra command in the for loop to move those files to their place in the folder named in `RECORDS`.
My batch file is so changed to:

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in (RECORDS) do (wfdb2mat -r %%~a -f 0 -t 20 > %%~am.info & move rec_*.* %%~a)
```

The problem is that `%%~a` contains folder name and file name together, like `Person1/rec_1` and I just need the folder name to move those files to.

How can I split these strings in order that I can extract folder name in each loop iteration?

Comment: `%%~nxa` should give you `rec_1` and `%%~dpa` should give `Person1/`. But you could use `Tokens 1-2` and `Delims=/` and use `%%a` for `Person1` and `%%b` for `rec_1`.

Comment: @Compo That's it, Thank you. Could you please post it as an answer to help others find the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my comment and my assumption of what your command is supposed to do

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Tokens=1-2 Delims=/" %%A In (RECORDS) Do (
    wfdb2mat -r %%A/%%B -f 0 -t 20 >%%A/%%Bm.info
    Move /Y %%B.* %%A)
```